# How to import SSRS shared datasets and data sources directly into BIDS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, reportbuilder3.0

Using:

- SSRS Report Server 10.50.1600.1
- BIDS Visual Studio 9.0.30729.4462 (from remote client on same domain and network; not local on SSRS server)

I'd like to be able to add existing shared data sources and shared datasets that live on my report server to my BIDS project on my local workstation.

I know I can create a shared resource from a BIDS instance, and deploy it to the SSRS server.  I can also do the same via Report Builder 3.0; deploy or publish from either application, then navigate to the report server URL (https://SSRSServer.mydomain.com/reportserver), download the resource(s) to my machine, add them as a Shared resource, and then redeploy as appropriate...but that's a bit convoluted.

What I'd like to do is add a shared data source (or set) in BIDS the same way that I can in Report Builder 3.0.  In RB, I can navigate to the report server URL (using WebDAV, I'm assuming), and pick the rsds file I need, however, from BIDS, I'm only able to browse UNC and local paths (URL+DAVWWWRoot doesn't work, and neither does [manually adding a data connection string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't find anything on the subject, and I've been racking my brain for too long this morning...

In short: is there anyway to browse my report server resources from BIDS 2008, in the same fashion as Report Builder 3.0 with the intention of adding existing datasets and data sources (please see screenshots for reference)?

*Image taken from adding a shared data source from Report Builder 3.0*
[image: From Report Builder 3.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sad to tell you but there is not.

You only can save those  objects ,local by downloading them and then adding to the project explicitly.

I checked if there is a way to paste multiple datasets/datasources into your project file but it is also not possible, looks like it is encrypted in the state string of the project file.

Comment: That's crazy.  I can't believe that's not a feature, but I've certainly seen crazier things. Nevertheless, I appreciate you chiming in.  I'm gonna leave the question open for a few more hours to see if anyone a viable workaround.  Thanks man.